# Where does Visual Studio generate the wsdl file?

Tags: visual-studio

Isn't visual studio supposed to automatically generate this file for each webservice creation ? If yes why can't I see it anywhere in project directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the now old-style .asmx web services -- no, they are not generated as a file, they are generated on the fly when you request 
http://localhost/project/service.asmx?wsdl